# WSO2 Mediator to parse a flat data?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a situation where I have to parse a flat data in CDATA section which involves a complex business logic and generate a XML request which can be sent to another service. Since generating the XML involves complex business logic which involves parsing the flat file, I don't think I can use existing WSO2 mediators such as XSLT etc can be used. I feel class mediator can be use. Any suggesation?

input:

2  019019
5  A4L01G0
5 $P200033450
56- A2A08
5- A2A14
5- A2A16
16- A2G01
10&- A2G02
7723- A2J04
5- A2K023
5- A2K03
767312365- A2P01
5- A2R12313107
512313- A2S02
6F01
6F02
36127316F03
6F04
900000000021]]

Expected output:
Say for example,

```
<RequestMessage> 
    <element1>1</element1>
    <element>Data</DCTLibraryName>
    <dummyy>PosinaManualLibraryCSet1</dummy>

    <DCTIDs>
        <elelemt10 attrib=" Base" attrib1="eweew" attrib2="GRR_D_PACK" Name="lib"/>
        <elelemt11 attrib ="Base" attrib1="10665" attrib2="temp" Name="lib"/>
>
</RequestMessage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are more happy with Java you could implement a custom mediator.

```
//some idea - this code never got tested in a real setup
public class MyCustomMediator extends AbstractMediator {
    public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) {
        //omitted any safety checks / exception handling 
        SynapseLog synLog = getLog(context);
        //adapt to your message
        OMElement element = (OMElement) context.getEnvelope().getBody()
                    .getFirstOMChild();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(
                    element.getText()));
        // your custom logic in here

        //return the result of your custom logic
        element.setText(result.toString());

        return true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use XSLT mediator.It has rich functions to read the CDATA section and compute xml out from that..XSLT is bit cost, but if your load is not high you can use XSLT. If you use class mediator all logic you have to implement..